# Regression Analysis for Percentile Ranks

Tags: statistics

Example: Is there a regression equation to estimate what a 8-11 yr old athlete's percentile rank score is, if all I have is data for 12-19 yr old athletes? For example, for a 15 yr old there vertical jump height of greater than 27 inches equates to a percentile rank of 99%. I have data of jump heights and percentile ranking for 15 yr olds from the 27 inches, down to less than 15.5 inches (2.5 percentile rank), and data for up to 19 yr olds. Can I estimate what 8, 9, 10, and 11 yr old vertical jump heights will be, and their corresponding percentile rankings from some type of estimation equation for the age group data I do have? Thank you!!